# Testing Socket Programming in C# on Windows Mobile 6 Emulator

Tags: c#, sockets, windows-mobile

I need to develop and test an application in Windows Mobile 6 for socket Programming in c#. I have done it in Windows Desktop application (i.e Creating a **Windows Console Application that acts as a Server** and listens. Then a **Windows Form Application that is the client**. Has a button and textbox. When i press the button the client gets connected to the server).

Now i have no idea how to check socket programming in windows Mobile 6. (Building a WM6 application that acts as a client and another that acts as sever something like that or should i be using a different approach? I am clueless)

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you just want to test your Windows Mobile 6 client then you can simply connect it to your Windows Desktop application.  Click on File > Configure > Network and check the Enable NE2000 option.  You can see [this blog post](http://www.brianpeek.com/blog/archive/2009/05/02/windows-virtual-pc-and-the-microsoft-device-emulator.aspx) to find out how to install the NE2000 driver.

Using Windows Mobile 6 as a client and Windows Desktop as the server is fine.  If you want to use the sockets over GPRS or CDMA then you should be aware of the fact your mobile device will likely have a dynamic IP (which can change as the handheld roams to other wireless networks) and will be behind NAT, so it can be difficult to push data out to the handheld without some kind of connection to the server initiated by the client.